# Plot cell array without loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, plot, cell

I have the following code:

```
SimRun = 0
Count = 0

for b = 1:0.5:3000
.
.
.
.
    Count = Count + 1;
    ArrayT(Count) = Time;
    ArrayTgo(Count) = tgo;
    ArrayY(Count) = Y;
    ArrayYD(Count) = YD;

end

SimRun = SimRun  + 1;
MAT_ArrayT{SimRun,:} = ArrayT;
MAT_ArrayTgo{SimRun,:} = ArrayTgo;
MAT_ArrayY{SimRun,:} = ArrayY;
MAT_ArrayYD{SimRun,:} = ArrayYD;
```

As you can see, I have 2 for loops. From the inner loop I receive a vector and from the outer loop I receive in the end a cell array where each cell is a vector.

Now, I had like to plot the cell array to plot basically around 6000 lines and I did it as follows:

```
for i = 1:SimRun

    figure(1)
    hold on
    plot(MAT_ArrayT{i,:},MAT_ArrayY{i,:})

    figure(2)
    hold on
    plot(MAT_ArrayT{i,:},MAT_ArrayYD{i,:})

end
```

However this solution takes pretty much time to draw all the lines.

Is there any better solution to store "lines" and plot all of them in one hit at the end?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plot` command takes a matrix and plots each column as a separate line. Assuming you have column vectors in your cell arrays, and they're all the same length, you can do this:

```
x = [MAT_ArrayT{:}];
y = [MAT_ArrayY{:}];
plot(x,y)
```

Even better would be to store those vectors in a numeric matrix to start with, so you don't need to make the extra copy.

Comment: Is there any idea how to add legend to such graph?

Comment: Look for the `legend` function. It takes a cell array of strings as input, one string per line plotted.