# Plot different length cell array without loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, plot, cell

I have the following output from a code:

```
MAT_ArrayT - 6x1 cell
MAT_ArrayY - 6x1 cell
```

Inside each of the it looks as following:

```
10000x1 double
9000x1 double
8000x1 double
7000x1 double
6000x1 double
5000x1 double
```

I would like to have a plot where I get 6 lines that fit to each other.

The result I want to get is as follows:

```
for i = 1:6
    plot(MAT_ArrayT{i,:},MAT_ArrayY{i,:})
end
```

but without for loop since it takes much longer where I need to draw 1k+ lines.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to plot 6 lines? the for loop is good for that, Why do you say 1K lines? Is not 6? also, if there are really 1K, then `plot` won't help you see anything. If you are genuinely plotting 1K lines its not the for loop the slow part, its the graphics output of your computer, too many things to plot

Comment: yes I have in the full code around 1k lines I just wanted to make the example clear so I gave 6. So according to what you say it depends more on my graphic card?

Comment: Its too much plotting, consider displaying it in a different way. with 1000 plots in the screen you wont be able to see much anyway

Comment: I ask because plotting in for loop and using hold takes a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty solution is as in my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48333424/7328782), padding the shorter vectors with `NaN`. `NaN` points are not plotted.

Answer (score -1):

If you hand Matlab's plot function an array, it will plot each column of the array as it's own line. For example:

```
A = 1:2:20;
B = 1:10;

C = [A', B']
plot(C)
```

Produces

```
C =

 1     1
 3     2
 5     3
 7     4
 9     5
11     6
13     7
15     8
17     9
19    10
```

[image: Plot of C]

As we can see, plot() has plotted the first column of C as the blue line, and the second column of C as the orange line, and we did it with just one line of code. If you can set up your cell arrays such that each line you want to plot is its own column, this should be able to speed things up for you.